# Proof that if $A\subset B$ then $A^* = B^*$

Tags: functional-analysis

I prove here that if $B$ is a Banach space, and $A$ is a closed subspace of $B$, $A\subset B$, then
$$A^* = B^*.$$
($A^*$ stands for the dual of $A$.)

There is obviously something wrong here but where?

We already have that $A^* \subset B^*$. The other inclusion comes from the following quick proof : Let $T\in B^*$, then there exists a constant $C$ s.t. for all $b\in B$, $|\langle T, b\rangle|\le C\|b\|$. Then for all $a\in A$, $|\langle T, a\rangle|\le C\|a\|$ thus $T$ belongs to $A^*$.

I already know counterexamples; where am I wrong in the proof?

Thanks.

Comment: "We already have that $A^\ast\subset B^\ast$." How? (That is wrong, by the way, in general.)

Comment: The mistake is that *we already have* $A^*\subset B^*$. Taking the dual acts contravariantly, i.e. it reverses inclusions and arrows of morphisms.

Comment: Well.... for example if $A$ and $B$ are Hilbert  then with Riesz Frechet theorem, $A^* = A$ and $B^* = B$ thus $A^* \subset B^*$.

Comment: @Vintarel That's a very special situation. In a Hilbert space, every closed subspace is complemented. Then you have an injection $A^\ast \hookrightarrow B^\ast$, since with $B \cong A\oplus C$, you have $B^\ast \cong A^\ast \times C^\ast$.

Comment: Have compared your proof with your counterexamples?

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered in comments:

> The mistake is that *we already have $A^∗\subset B^∗$*. Taking the dual acts contravariantly, i.e. it reverses inclusions and arrows of morphisms. –  Your Ad Here Jan 28 at 16:09